# Python object instantiation at the start of file or inside a method?

Tags: python, oop

Is it preferred to instantiate an object at the start of a file or inside of a method of a class? For example:

```
# start of file
foo = Foo()
class Bar(object):
    def bar(self):
        foo.some_method()
```

or

```
# start of file
class Bar(object):
    def bar(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.some_method()
```

Is there any performance difference as well?

Comment: There is an error in your examples, it should be `def bar(self)` and `self.foo = Foo()`, `self.foo.some_method()` in the second example. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I've edited the def bar(self). I don't mean to save the instantiated object, feel free to tell if there is a better way than the 2 options I've stated

Comment: Uh, but these two examples are not equal! In the first one, someone else can call another method from class Foo and change its state. But in the second example, foo object is destroyed every time at the end of bar function and a new one is created at the beginning of bar function. If you add `self.foo = Foo()` in `__init__(self)`, these two examples became functional equal, i.e someone else also can change state `Foo` object by calling `xxx.foo.some_method()` if xxx is object of class Bar

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with this and hoist out the `Foo()` one level at a time:

```
class Bar(object):
    def bar(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.some_method()
```

This creates a `Foo` each time the method is called. The `Foo` only exists as long as the method body.

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
    def bar(self):
        self.foo.some_method()
```

This creates a `Foo` once for each time a `Bar` is created. The `Foo` exists as long as the `Bar` that created it.

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
    def bar(self):
        if self.foo is None:
           self.foo = Foo()
        self.foo.some_method()
```

This is a variant of the prior that only creates the `Foo` when the `bar` method is called. The `None` state of the `foo` can be hidden using a property.

```
foo = Foo()
class Bar(object):
    def bar(self):
        foo.some_method()
```

This creates a `Foo` only once which is then reused. The `Foo` exists until the program exits.

None of these are preferred each has its own moment of applicability.